# BINGMapsRESTToolkit project from Git seems to force RouteOption Avoid.Highways

Tags: c#, github, bing-maps

I am converting a BING Maps v6.3 app in C# to use BING Maps Version 8. For this converted app I am now using the BINGMapsRESTToolkit from Git. When I use the toolkit to calculate a route, it forces RouteOption = Avoid.Highways.

Just to confirm behaviour of BING Maps v8, I have a similar app in HTML/Javascript with the same functionality working correctly, using BING Maps version 8: the javascript version does not force RouteOption = Avoid.Highways.

Looking into the internals of the BINGMapsRESTToolkit, I think the culprit is the Enum for AvoidType (as defined in AvoidType.cs): it is missing the value for Avoid.None. This is listed in the MSDN documentation, and behaves correctly when called from javascript: i.e. when NOT using the BINGMapsRESTToolkit.

Here is a start and end coordinate pair which demonstrates the issue:
from: -36.809770, 144.469720
to: -36.755100, 144.279590

Use BING Maps options: travelmode = driving, optimize = distance, units=kilometres, avoid = none

html/javascript app gives distance 21.563 km.
Here is the distance, time and route from the response:
Distance for leg 1: 21.563 km, Time for leg 1: 26 minutes, 33 seconds

1   Leave Enright Rd towards Emerald Hill Dr
2   Turn right on to Emerald Hill Dr
3   Turn left on to Giris Rd
4   Turn left on to McIvor Hwy / B280
5   At roundabout, take 2nd exit
6   At roundabout, take 3rd exit on to Chapel St
7   Turn left on to Farmer Ln
8   Turn right on to Park Rd
9   Turn left on to Gaol Rd
10  Turn left on to road
11  Arrive on the right

BINGMapsRESTToolkit (toolkit version 1.1.4), gives 21.838 km
parameters: travel mode = driving, optimize = distance, units = km,
avoid not specified
Here is the URL generated by the toolkit:
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/Driving?&wp.0=-36.80977,144.46972&wp.1=-36.7551,144.27959&o=xml&optmz=Distance&du=kilometer&key=MY_BING_MAPS_KEY&clientApi=CSToolkit

and the output response:
Results:
distance = 21.838 kilometer, time = 1777 Second
Leg #1
1. Depart Enright Rd toward Emerald Hill Dr
2. Turn right onto Shanahans Rd
3. Bear right onto Strathfieldsaye Rd / C327
4. At roundabout, take 3rd exit
5. At roundabout, take 3rd exit onto Williamson St
6. Bear right onto Brougham St
7. Turn left onto Mundy St
8. Pass through 2 roundabouts, remaining on Mundy St
9. Turn left onto McCrae St / Pall Mall / A300, and then immediately turn right onto Park Rd
10. Turn left onto Gaol Rd
11. Turn left onto road
12. Arrive on the right

When the html/javascript is run with routeavoidance= avoid highways
and all other options remaining the same, we get the following:

Distance for leg 1: 21.838 km
Time for leg 1: 29 minutes, 37 seconds  (equiv: 1777 seconds)

1   Leave Enright Rd towards Emerald Hill Dr
2   Turn right on to Shanahans Rd
3   Bear right on to Strathfieldsaye Rd / C327
4   At roundabout, take 3rd exit
5   At roundabout, take 3rd exit on to Williamson St
6   Bear right on to Brougham St
7   Turn left on to Mundy St
8   Pass through 2 roundabouts, remaining on Mundy St
9   Turn left on to McCrae St / Pall Mall / A300, and then immediately turn right on to Park Rd
10  Turn left on to Gaol Rd
11  Turn left on to road
12  Arrive on the right

As promised, I have provided details of the route generated in all cases.

As you can see, the route generated when the BING MAPS Control version 8 is run with routeavoidance=avoid highways, the result is identical to that which we get from the BINGMAPSRestToolkit v1.1.4, with no route avoidance specified.

The issue here is that the route request specifies Optimize for shortest distance. The BING Maps Control v8 appears to do this correctly; i.e. it returns the route with the shortest distance: in this case 21.536 km.

This distance is less than the distance provided by the BINGMAPSRESTToolkit v1.1.4, when provided with the same waypoints, and given the same route request options: the toolkit produces 21.838 km, which is clearly greater than 21.536 km.

Anyone out there encountered this issue?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I just double checked the source code, it does not force avoid highways. In fact there is not avoid parameters set by default, you need to pass in a list of avoid options that you want in the request. If you don't pass in any, then none get added to the request. The only way avoid highways would be added to your request is in your code.

There is roughly a 100M routing requests going through this library a month and no-one else has reported this issue, and if it was an issue in the library itself, I'm sure others would have reported it by now.

Comment: Thank you Ricky Brundritt for your quick response. I have added details of the . waypoints used, together with the response route for three cases: a) html/javascript with no route avoidance, b) toolkit with no avoid specified, c) html/javascript with avoid highways specified.  It is clear that the BING MAPS REST service provides a distance of 21.838 km, whereas the BING MAPS v8 Map Control provides a distance of 21.536 km, for a Route request with the same set of waypoints, optimization, travel mode, and with no route avoidance specified.